# Firefox по умолчанию отмечает первый радио инпут

Tags: html

У меня есть несколько инпутов  и когда в Firefox загружаю страницу уже отмечен первый инпут, в остальных броузерах все нормально
Подскажите как сделать чтобы Firefox сам не отмечал радио инпуты

Comment: Вообще, radiobutton по своей природе должен стоять в каком-то положении, так что правильнее указать `selected` для того положения, которое наименее вероятно останется выбранным.

Answer (score 3):

Radio input всегда будет выбран первый из группы одноименных инпутов. Если нужно, чтобы пользователь обязательно сделал свой выбор, добавьте дополнительный пункт, например:

- не выбрано
- пункт 1
- пункт 2
- ...

но такое поведение обычно свойственно конструкции `<select>..<option>`.

Если же вы имеете ввиду, что при обновлении страницы все браузеры сбрасывают значение инпутов, а файрфокс нет, то выход такой: `<input type='radio' ... autocomplete='off'>`

Answer (score 2):

Firefox просто запоминает выбранный input при перезагрузки страницы, а остальные броузеры сбрасывают

Answer (score 0):

> Firefox просто запоминает выбранный input при перезагрузки страницы

Чтобы отключить `автозаполнение` нужно поставить `autocomplete="off"`

Можно сделать так

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
});
```

Или так

```
<input type="radio" autocomplete="off">
```